# How to change the size of custom view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, xib

I want to use custom `UIView` in my iOS app, and so I created xib as well as `.swift` file in order to create UI components interactively in the xib. However, the size on the size inspector of the custom view is disabled for some reasons, and hence I cannot change the size of the custom view.

Why is it disabled? And how can I change the size of it?

Because I cannot change the size of it currently, the resultant custom view goes beyond the entire window of the Simulator.

I use Swift and iOS 8 on Xcode 6.1 Beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the size to freeform from Retina 3.5 Full Screen in the 4th tab of your right pane of the .xib file and you can change the size of your view.

[image: .xib information]